# If two continuous maps coincide in dense set, then they are the same

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $f,g : R \to R $ are continuous and $D \subset \mathbb{R}$ is dense. Suppose $f(x) = g(x) $ for all $x \in D$. Does it follow that $f(x) = g(x) $ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$??

My answer is affirmative. Suppose $h(x) = f(x) - g(x) $. By hypothesis,

$$ D = \{ x : h(x) = 0 \} $$

but we know $\{ x : h(x) = 0 \} $ is closed since $h$ is continuous. and so $\{ x : h = 0 \} = \overline{ \{ x : h = 0 \} } = \overline{D} = \mathbb{R} $ as desired.

Is this right? thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Yes that works.

Comment: You "only" know that there is a dense *subset* $D$ of $\{x:h(x)=0\}$. The conclusion is the same, but careful.

Answer (score 1):

**An other way**

Let $x\in \mathbb R\backslash D$.
By density of $D$ in $\mathbb R$, there is a sequence $(x_n)\subset D$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty }x_n=x$. By continuity of $f$ and $g$ on $\mathbb R$ and by the fact that $f(x_n)=g(x_n)$ for all $n$,
$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty }f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty }g(x_n)=g(x),$$
what prove the claim.